# aligning text box label with the text box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap. I want the text `label`s for the `input`s to be aligned left of the text boxes edge, not above in the center as they are now.

Is this something that is done with bootstrap?

**EDIT**: Sorry the code snippet did not show my problem properly so i redid it in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfmxt3kv/).

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="text-center col-xs-12  ">
  <div class="row">
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-xs-6 ">
      <label for="companyInput">LABEL</label>
      <br />
      <input id="companyInput" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 ">
      LABEL
      <br />
      <input id="cardInput" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the bootstrap form-control styles?

Comment: Yes. I dont know how bootstrap is supposed to work. I got this thing i my lap and apparently it has boostrap. So i assume it should be solved with boostrap techniques. Please do explain. I while google form-control styles.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### EDIT:

I updated your fiddle, here - https://jsfiddle.net/Lfmxt3kv/1/

If you have to have `text-center` on the parent container, then you'll need a wrapper div around your label and input element. Here are the changes I made to the fiddle:

```
<div class="text-center col-xs-12">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-xs-6 ">
      <!-- .input-wrapper needs to be wrapped around both the label and input element -->
      <div class="input-wrapper">
        <label for="companyInput">LABEL</label>
        <input id="companyInput" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 ">
      <div class="input-wrapper">
        <label for="cardInput">LABEL</label>
        <input id="cardInput" type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.input-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

.input-wrapper label {
  display: block;
}
```

---

<s>Just adding [`text-left`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment) looks like it works.</s>

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
  LABEL ONE
  <br />
  <input id="companyInput" type="text" placeholder="Företag... (1-100)">
</div>
```

Comment: Works, but isn't the bootstrap way of handling it.

Comment: Sorry. I updated the question with a jsFiddle cause it was not displaying my problem correctly. Plz have a look.

Comment: @Lautaro, I've updated my answer. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for [Bootstrap forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

> Individual form controls automatically receive some global styling.
>   All textual `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>` elements with
>   `.form-control` are set to `width: 100%;` by default. Wrap labels and
>   controls in `.form-group` for optimum spacing.

For what you want, you need to `display:inline-block`  the `.form-group` and add class `text-left` to align left because `.container` has `text-center`

### Snippet

```css
.form-group {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="text-center container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <form class="form">
        <div class="form-group text-left">
          <label for="companyInput">Company</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="companyInput" type="text" placeholder="Företag... (1-100)">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group text-left">
          <label for="cardInput">Card</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="cardInput" type="text" placeholder="Kort... (1-100)" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But my text boxes are supposed to be side by side. Not vertically.

Comment: @Lautaro ***This only applies to forms within viewports that are at least 768px wide.***,  Hit "Full page" to see result

Comment: Sorry. I updated the question with a jsFiddle cause it was not displaying my problem correctly. Plz have a look.

Comment: @Lautaro did you look at my comment plus updated answer?

Comment: yes i did. The label should be on top of the inputs. Have a look at the fiddle.

Comment: @Lautaro now I understood what you want, I updated my answer, take a look

Comment: Thanks. Problem now is that both inputs are just floated to The Left. Can you see How they are placed in my fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

for a quick fix you could add a class to the div..

```
<div class="textalign col-span-6">
```

then in css just do

```
.textalign { text-align: left; }
```

Comment: FYI, Bootstrap already has text-alignment utility classes built in. You could add `text-left` to achieve the same thing. See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment for more details.